# Python Lazy Module with Dependency Injection

Tags: python, python-module

I want to build a python module with ergonomic lazy injections. Concretely, here's an example of what I want:

my_module.py

```
x = 4
y = x
```

injector.py

```
m = lazy_import("my_module")
m.x = 5
print(m.y)
```

This should print 5.

In reality, I want to write a much larger program than this.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: If I simply use import, this obviously won't work. I'm not aware of what python feature enables me to do lazy programming well like this. So it's not a "try" question, it's a knowledge question.